# PHP for MySQL: Escaping user input to be used with `LIKE` and `REGEXP` functions

Tags: php, mysql, escaping, sql-injection, user-input

Thanks to [hakra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367456/hakra) I thought I should create a canonical question from my [original question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994134/php-mysql-preparing-user-defined-search-terms-for-query).

Escaping a user input to be used with MySQL `LIKE` and `REGEXP` functions safely (to prevent SQL injections and other undesired possibilities) do you think these solutions are enough? Suppose the input is a single word in the following examples. Otherwise it can easily be processed by a function.

### for `LIKE`

```
$input = '__35%';
$inputModf = strtr($input,array('\\'=>'\\\\','%'=>'\\%','_'=>'\\_'));
$inputModf = '%' . [db escape $inputModf here] . '%';
```

where query is like `... WHERE field LIKE '$inputModf'`

### for `REGEXP`

```
$input = '$35.2';
$spaces = '[[:blank:]]|[[:punct:]]|[[:space:]]';
$inputModf = preg_quote($input);
$inputModf = '(^|'.$spaces.')'.[db escape $inputModf here].'($|'.$spaces.')';
```

where query is like `... WHERE field REGEXP '$inputModf'`

Comment: Its bad practice to use `%` in both end of your Like Query rather than that `mysqli_real_escape_string` and `filter_var` would do the Job just fine

Comment: @Baba what exactly do you mean by "using it in both end"? If it's a `LIKE` value and if it's searched like `%value%` it's more a necessity than a choice in fact.

Comment: If you search something like '%value%' is very bad for performance and not a good practice

Comment: @Baba - How else do you suggest a query that would return the appropriate results?

Comment: You can use Full Text Search http://devzone.zend.com/26/using-mysql-full-text-searching/ for use `%value` & `value%` that is a better faster way for optimized search result see http://www.ovaistariq.net/479/mysql-query-optimization-tip-1-avoid-using-wildcard-character-at-the-start-of-a-like-pattern/

Comment: @Baba fulltext feature is not natively supported by all table types, notably by **InnoDB**. And my question in this specific post is not about searching a db. It's about escaping user input for MySQL `LIKE` and `REGEXP` functions.